# How do I install the latest Indy10 in Delphi 2007 for .NET?

Tags: delphi, delphi-2007, indy

Can someone please point me to instructions for installing the latest Indy10 in Delphi 2007 for .NET?  I'm not exactly sure how that works for the .NET side.

Currently, I use the Indy10 assemblies that shipped with Delphi 2007.  I have the latest Tiburon branch of Indy10.  My preference would be to build directly from the Pascal source in Delphi 2007 for .NET, although I'll use newly-built assemblies if necessary.

Do I just need to build some package or other?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indy's ...Net packages (such as IndySystem100Net, etc...) are for Delphi.NET.  However, there are some issues in the current Tiburon branch code that prevents Indy from fully compiling under .NET correctly.